# How to implement a generic helper to handle errors using switchmap, pipe, map and catchError

Tags: typescript, rxjs, refactoring, ngrx

This is a code that has a pattern that is repeated many times in current code

```js
loadBasicStateInfo$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.loadBasicStateInfo),
    switchMap(args => this.configurationService.getBasicStateInfo()
        .pipe(
            map(response => actions.loadBasicStateInfoComplete({ basicStateInfo: new BasicStateInfo(response.result) })),
            catchError(() => of(actions.loadBasicStateInfoFailure({ error: 'fail' })))
        )
    )
));

loadClientServerMinutesOffset$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.loadClientServerMinutesOffset),
    switchMap(args => this.configurationService.getClientServerMinutesOffset()
        .pipe(
            map(response => actions.loadClientServerMinutesOffsetComplete({ clientServerMinutesOffset: response.result })),
            catchError(() => of(actions.loadClientServerMinutesOffsetFailure({ error: 'fail' })))
        )
    )
));

loadSetting$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(actions.loadSettings),
    switchMap(args => this.configurationService.getSettingsByNamesForUser(args.settingNames)
        .pipe(
            map(response => actions.loadSettingsCompleted({ settings: response.result })),
            catchError(() => of(actions.loadSettingsFailure({ error: 'fail' })))
        )
    )
));
```

I'm very new to typescript but I would like to refactor into some helper method, this is what I have as starting point

```js
import { Actions, createEffect } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

class effectHelper {

    public create(act: Actions, type: any, apiCall: any, methodForMap: any, methodForError: any) {
        return createEffect(() => act.pipe(
            ofType(type),
            switchMap(apiCall.pipe(
                map(methodForMap)),
                catchError(methodForError))
        ));
    }
}
```

How can I implement a generic helper like above is that possible ? and how can it be achieved ?

**UPDATE**

actions are ngrx Actions that are declared this way

```js
export const loadClientServerMinutesOffset = createAction('[Configuration] Load Client Server Minutes Offset');
export const loadClientServerMinutesOffsetComplete = createAction('[Configuration] Load Client Server Minutes Offset Completed',
    props<{ clientServerMinutesOffset: number }>());
export const loadClientServerMinutesOffsetFailure = createAction('[Configuration] Load Client Server Minutes Offset Failed', props<{ error: any }>());
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with NgRx but it's very similar to Redux which I am familiar with.

We want to create a set of the three actions for a given API call.  We need to know the base name for the actions, the API function, and how to map from the API response to the data for the "Complete" action, which would be `response => ({ clientServerMinutesOffset: response.result })`

The piece that I'm unsure about is where the `Actions` object comes from and whether this should be an argument of the parent `createApiActions` function or something that you pass to the `effect` function.

The most annoying part of typing this with a generic is that the `createAction` function uses a type `NotAllowedCheck<P>` to validate arguments.  If you just have a generic `P extends object` then you'll get errors that `P` is not assignable to `NotAllowedCheck<P>`. `mapResponse` is basically just `(response: Res) => R` but I had to define it as `FunctionWithParametersType<[Res], R & NotAllowedCheck<R>>` in order to avoid these errors.

```
import { Actions, createEffect, ofType } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { createAction, FunctionWithParametersType, NotAllowedCheck } from "@ngrx/store";
import { catchError, switchMap, map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { of, Observable } from "rxjs";

const createApiActions = <Args extends object, Res, R extends object>(
  actions: Actions,
  category: string,
  apiCall: (args: Args) => Observable<Res>,
  mapResponse: FunctionWithParametersType<[Res], R & NotAllowedCheck<R>>
) => {
  const pending = createAction(
    `[${category}] Pending`,
    (args: Args & NotAllowedCheck<Args>) => args
  );

  const complete = createAction<string, [Res], R>(
    `[${category}] Complete`,
    mapResponse
  );

  const failure = createAction(
    `[${category}] Failure`, 
    () => ({ error: "fail" })
  );

  const effect = createEffect(() =>
    actions.pipe(
      ofType(pending),
      switchMap((args) =>
        apiCall(args).pipe(
          map((response) => complete(response)),
          catchError(() => of(failure()))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  return {
    pending,
    complete,
    failure,
    effect
  };
};
```

This helper creates the set of three action creators and the effect. The effect has the same structure as before, but now we can replace your hard-coded actions with variables.

You would use it like this:

```
const loadSettings = createApiActions(
  actions,
  'loadSettings',
  (args: {settingNames: string[]}) => this.configurationService.getSettingsByNamesForUser(args.settingNames),
  (response: SomeType) => ({ settings: response.result }),
)
```

```
loadSettings.pending({settingNames: ["someSetting"]})
```

At this point I've realized that defining `Args` as an `object` doesn't work in the cases which don't require any arguments.  So my types need more work.  But I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for your very detailed answer, In case you are interested I have included details of where actions come from at the end of my question

Comment: what is an example of what `actions` contains, is it an array? is only until now that we are discussing this with team.